# Why is my unity scene script not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

using a button to load a scene and iam just getting the error "Assets\Scripts\button_press.cs(15,59): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Object' to 'string'"

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class button_press : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Object sceneToLoad;




   public void PlayGame ()
   {
       UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);
   }

   public void QuitGame()
   {
       Debug.Log (" You have quit");
       Application.Quit();
   }
}
```

Comment: The scene API in Unity expects strings. If you still want to assign scene assets in the inspector, you could try [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/242794/inspector-field-for-scene-asset.html#answer-1204071). I have used it in the past and it worked well. Also look at the improvements in the comments there.

Answer (score 2):

The [LoadScene API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) expects either an integer referring to the scene number in the build, or a string referring to the name of the scene (generally preferred).

You should define your `sceneToLoad` field as a string rather than an Object.